# There is a error that I need help fixing! Sorting is not working properly in my program

Tags: vb.net

I have this code that I have been working on where the whole goal is to get the content of 2 files, sort it in order from lowest to greatest and output it. The error that I have been getting is that the numbers in the array do sort but not in order from lowest to greatest.

I have three text files labelled Input1.txt and Input2.txt and an output text file.

The content in Input1 is as follows: 
5
3
2
1
9
12
34

The content in Input2 is as follows:
4
13
16
23
56
-7

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Imports System.IO


Public Class Form1
    'Calling up a filepath for saving the users input plus altered input [file names]
    Public filePath As String = "Input1.TXT"
    Public filePath2 As String = "Input2.TXT"
    Public outputFile As String = "Output.txt"
    Public objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath)
    Public objReader1 As New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath2)


    Dim line As String
    'Temp Variables

    Dim TempS As String
    Dim TempY As String
    Dim iPass As Integer
    Dim iTemp As Integer



    'Declaring variable for how many numbers there are in TextFileNumbes.txt (I have listed 6 numbers in this case)
    Dim numbers(100) As String
    'Declaring variable for creating a counter for reading all the numbers in TextFileNumbers.txt
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    'Event - To Load Name From TextFile
    Public Sub BtnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
        If objReader.Peek() <> -1 Then
            'Read one line from the input textfile
            TempS = objReader.ReadLine()


            'Declaring code for placing the numbers into an array
            numbers(i) = TempS
            'Add name read to listbox
            ListBox1.Items.Add(TempS)
            'Add numbers to the listBox titled "Data Combined From Both Files"
            ListBox2.Items.Add(numbers(i))
            'Increment Array
            i += 1

        Else
            'Prompts User End of File Has Been Reached
            MessageBox.Show("End of File Has Been Reached!")

        End If


    End Sub

    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If objReader1.Peek() <> -1 Then
            'Read one line from the input textfile
            TempY = objReader1.ReadLine()

            'Declaring code for placing the numbers into an array
            numbers(i) = TempY
            'Add name read to listbox
            lstBoxInputFile.Items.Add(TempY)
            'Declaring code for the numbers/data stored in TextFileNumbers to be passed onto the OriginalData listbox
            ListBox2.Items.Add(numbers(i))
            'Increment array counter
            i += 1




        Else
            'If file not located, prompts user that the file isn't there
            MessageBox.Show("End of File Has Been Reached!")

        End If


    End Sub
    'Event - save the user input plus altered text
    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    End Sub
    'Event to clear output textfile


    Public Sub btnSort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSort.Click


        For iPass = 1 To numbers.Length - 1
            For i = 0 To numbers.Length - 2
                If numbers(i) > numbers(i + 1) Then
                    iTemp = numbers(i)
                    numbers(i) = numbers(i + 1)
                    numbers(i + 1) = iTemp
                End If
            Next i
        Next iPass
        Dim sortOut As String
        For i = 0 To numbers.Length - 1

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(numbers(i)) Then
                ListBox3.Items.Add(numbers(i))
            End If


        Next
        MessageBox.Show("The Data has been sorted!")

    End Sub
End Class
```

The output that I have been getting is as follows: -7, 1, 12, 13, 16, 2, 23,3, 34,4, 5, 56, 9 when it should be -7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9,  12, 13, 16, 23, 34, 56

Comment: Use a `List(Of Integer)`, which already has the functions built in for you... Also turn `Option Strict On`, you're playing with the devil without it which proves on the issue's you are seeing.

Comment: Also, what is wrong with the answer provided [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55168298/1797425) by Joel; he has a few examples. Have you tried them, what was the output, what isn't working etc? Please explain this instead of creating new questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean by variable has been used before it has been assigned a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163633/what-does-it-mean-by-variable-has-been-used-before-it-has-been-assigned-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem that perhaps you're trying to run before you can walk.

You're reading the data from a text file into an array of strings and then trying to compare string values. This line ..

```
If numbers(i) > numbers(i + 1) Then
```

Is comparing strings, not integers. What is actually happening when you compare a string to see which is greater is that the first character (not number, it could be an 'a' or '/' or '3') it then compares the value of the character code. and then decides which is a higher value and does this for all the characters in each string that you're comparing. Also if the number of characters in a string is different, then the string with the least number of  characters will be deemed less than the longer string. Kind makes sense.

So .. looking at a particular triplet in your list of numbers, "16", "2" and "23"

The comparison code has compared "16" and "2" at some point and because the first characters are "1" and "2", "16" is less than "2".

The comparison between "2" and "23" is slightly different be cause although the first characters are the same, "2" is shorter than "23" and because of this "2" is less than "23"

To compare numbers properly, you have to convert or parse the each string value into a number value and store it as a number - not a string. Have a look at this and compare the differences with your code ..

```
Public Class Form1
    'Calling up a filepath for saving the users input plus altered input [file names]
    Public filePath As String = "Input1.TXT"
    Public filePath2 As String = "Input2.TXT"
    Public outputFile As String = "Output.txt"
    Public objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath)
    Public objReader1 As New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath2)


    'Temp Variables
    Dim TempS As Integer
    Dim TempY As Integer
    Dim iPass As Integer
    Dim iTemp As Integer

    'Declaring variable for how many numbers there are in TextFileNumbes.txt (I have listed 6 numbers in this case)
    Dim numbers(100) As Integer
    'Declaring variable for creating a counter for reading all the numbers in TextFileNumbers.txt
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    'Event - To Load Name From TextFile
    Public Sub BtnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
        If objReader.Peek() <> -1 Then
            'Read one line from the input textfile
            TempS = Integer.Parse(objReader.ReadLine())
            'Declaring code for placing the numbers into an array
            numbers(i) = TempS
            'Add name read to listbox
            ListBox1.Items.Add(TempS)
            'Add numbers to the listBox titled "Data Combined From Both Files"
            ListBox2.Items.Add(numbers(i))
            'Increment Array
            i += 1
        Else
            'Prompts User End of File Has Been Reached
            MessageBox.Show("End of File Has Been Reached!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If objReader1.Peek() <> -1 Then
            'Read one line from the input textfile
            TempY = Integer.Parse(objReader1.ReadLine())
            'Declaring code for placing the numbers into an array
            numbers(i) = TempY
            'Add name read to listbox
            lstBoxInputFile.Items.Add(TempY.ToString)
            'Declaring code for the numbers/data stored in TextFileNumbers to be passed onto the OriginalData listbox
            ListBox2.Items.Add(numbers(i).ToString)
            'Increment array counter
            i += 1
        Else
            'If file not located, prompts user that the file isn't there
            MessageBox.Show("End of File Has Been Reached!")
        End If
    End Sub

    'Event - save the user input plus altered text
    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    End Sub
    'Event to clear output textfile

    Public Sub btnSort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSort.Click
        For iPass = 1 To numbers.Length - 1
            For i = 0 To numbers.Length - 2
                If numbers(i) > numbers(i + 1) Then
                    iTemp = numbers(i)
                    numbers(i) = numbers(i + 1)
                    numbers(i + 1) = iTemp
                End If
            Next i
        Next iPass
        For i = 0 To numbers.Length - 1
            ListBox3.Items.Add(numbers(i).ToString)
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("The Data has been sorted!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

All your temporary variables now defined as integers. When VB.Net is comparing actual numbers and not strings, `1` is now seen as less than `16`. Voila.

The lines that declare the variables `line` and `sortout` have been removed in my example because your code doesn't use them.

You'll also notice that I've added `.ToString` in several places. This isn't strictly necessary as VB will happily convert Integers to Strings in the background, but I've added them to let you know that it happens.